# can we open a new empty browser window within existing webdriver instance? (selenium-Java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to open a new browser window using existing webdriver instance, without clicking an link on existing browser window.

I tried using actions class, robot class, and java script method,

```java
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.open();");
```

Comment: Did you try sending the key chord `Ctrl+N` to the browser?

Comment: You mean `Ctrl+T` or `Ctrl+N` ?

Comment: Yes, i tried above methods. Its not working. Yes i meant You mean Ctrl+T or Ctrl+N ?